# two submit buttons, with confirmation pop up only on one submit button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, confirm

I have two submit buttons in a form that Lets user Update/ Delete content. I want a confirm pop only if the user clicks Delete button.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function confirmation() {
        // I need to know which submit button was pressed.
       if (value==Delete){
        var answer = confirm("Cancel?")
            if (answer){
                    return true;
            //Continue as intended
            }
            else{
             return false
            }
      }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="Edit_Data">
//form input fields go here
<input name="action"  type="submit" onclick="confirmation()" value="Update">
<input name="action"  type="submit" onclick="confirmation()" value="Delete">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Both your buttons are not the type of `submit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have several problems with your code.  The value in your if statement is an undefined variable secondly you need to put quotes around the delete.  Here is working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SMBWd/ and the relevant code change.  Also, I would encourage you to look how to do this without using javascript in your HTML.

```
function confirmation(e) {
        // I need to know which submit button was pressed.
       if (e.value=='Delete'){
```

and in the HTML

```
<input name="action"  type="button" onclick="confirmation(this)" value="Update">
<input name="action"  type="button" onclick="confirmation(this)" value="Delete">
```

Comment: Sorry about the code mistakes. I tried your code, it does the job of showing the pop up. But even if I click cancel on the pop up confirmation, the form still continues to go ahead. Can you check it with action="http://www.google.com" ?

Comment: @aVC here is a new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SMBWd/3/ there are several changes.  This is a somewhat messy way of doing it, but it gives you the idea.

Comment: Thanks It looks good, except in my actual code, If I use type="submit" for the two buttons, it seems to fail. Is it supposed to?

Comment: @aVC You need to use `type="button"`

Answer (score 0):

For your onclick event definition in the html tag, why not call separate functions?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to NOT call the javascript on the Update button.

If your form is static, then you do this in your IDE. If it's dynamic, then the dynamic code can create the form element accordingly.

If the form elements are generated automatically, then you should setup an event handler in JavaScript dynamically. Find all elements of type input with type attribute button or submit, and assign

```
elems[i].onclick = confirmation;
```

You'd then get the event object as a method parameter, and you could query that for the value of the button.

Comment: J,Thanks bud, for the reply. I am very much a novice in JS. Hopefully in the long run, i will look into details on your suggestions and will implement it. :)